# Adding numbers to marker in mapbox android

Tags: java, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

I'm trying to figure out how to add numbers to markers programmatically in mapbox to get the result of the image below

[MARKERS WITH NUMBERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssm4c.png)

Here is the code of the map that displays some markers

```
public class DepartMissionFragment extends Fragment {
    private MapView mapView;

    private static final String TAG = "DirectionsActivity";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(requireActivity(), getString(R.string.access_token));
        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mission_depart, container, false);

        mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView20);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(33.589886, -7.603869))
                        .title("marker one"));
// It is possible to use .setIcon() to get a custom icon from ressources


                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(33.589790, -7.603989))
                        .title("marker two"));

                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(33.589190, -7.603089))
                        .title("marker three"));


                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(33.588790, -7.603289))
                        .title("etc.."));

                mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(33.580790, -7.603989))
                        .title("etc...."));
                mapboxMap.setStyle(getString(R.string.navigation_guidance_day), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {


                    }
                });

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

I'm searching for a way to give numbers to the markers, a proper way for me would be to add custom marker from drawable.

Any other method is welcomed.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far and what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152085/add-text-programmatically-inside-drawable-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than displaying markers with the `MapboxMap#addMarker` method and depending on a drawable resource, you could add icons from coordinates stored as GeoJSON features using a symbol layer, as shown in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-symbol-layer/) for the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android.

When adding each `Feature` representing a coordinate to the a [GeoJSON](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/geojson/) object, you could add a property to each `Feature`'s `properties` object containing the number to display on the marker for this coordinate. Then, in addition to the `iconImage` added with `SymbolLayer#setProperties` as shown in the example, you could also add a `textField` for each symbol populated by the property added to the GeoJSON. This [symbol layer clustering example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/) shows a similar workflow applied to a clustering use case. The difference between the clustering example and your implementation will mainly be that, rather than obtaining the number to display from a clustered count, you will be obtaining it from a GeoJSON property which you specified for the coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

In v10, Marker means annotation and we can achieve multiple marker like this:

```
    var markerList :ArrayList<PointAnnotationOptions> = ArrayList()
            var annotationApi : AnnotationPlugin? = null
            lateinit var annotaionConfig : AnnotationConfig
            var pointAnnotationManager : PointAnnotationManager? = null
            var mapView: MapView? = null
            val layerID = "map_annotation";
            
            mapView = findViewById(R.id.map);
            mapView?.getMapboxMap()?.loadStyleUri(
                   Style.MAPBOX_STREETS,
                   object : Style.OnStyleLoaded {
                            createMarkerList()
                            annotationApi = mapView?.annotations
                            annotaionConfig = AnnotationConfig(
                                      layerId = layerID
                            )
                           pointAnnotationManager = annotationApi?.createPointAnnotationManager(annotaionConfig)!!
    
                            }
                   }
           )
        
        fun createMarkerList(){
          markerList =  ArrayList();
          for (i in 0 until 5) {
          bitmapFromDrawableRes(context!!.applicationContext,R.drawable.doctor_online
              )?.let {
            val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions = 
            PointAnnotationOptions()
                .withPoint(Point.fromLngLat(latLng!!.longitude,latLng!!.latitude))
                .withIconImage(it)
                .withData(Gson().fromJson(data.toString(), JsonElement::class.java))
                .withIconSize(2.0)
           markerList.add(pointAnnotationOptions);
            } 
         }
         // For Creating marker
         pointAnnotationManager?.create(markerList)
       }

private fun convertDrawableToBitmap(sourceDrawable: Drawable?): Bitmap? {
        if (sourceDrawable == null) {
            return null
        }
        return if (sourceDrawable is BitmapDrawable) {
            sourceDrawable.bitmap
        } else {
// copying drawable object to not manipulate on the same reference
            val constantState = sourceDrawable.constantState ?: return null
            val drawable = constantState.newDrawable().mutate()
            val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            drawable.draw(canvas)
            bitmap
        }
    }
```